# Auto Changing Background

Tags: html, background, background-image

Is there a possible code to be able to auto change a background in every 15 or 20 seconds in HTML, since I'm more used to incorporating the styles in HTML. It's for a project where we're needed to make a login and signup page with a database and any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Requires javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course theirs a way to do that but its going to require some CSS. But you can use the following code.

```css
@keyframes bgcolor {
    0% {
        background-color: #45a3e5
    }

    30% {
        background-color: #66bf39
    }

    60% {
        background-color: #eb670f
    }

    90% {
        background-color: #f35
    }

    100% {
        background-color: #864cbf
    }
}

body {
    -webkit-animation: bgcolor 20s infinite;
    animation: bgcolor 10s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

This was linked from another stack overflow post you may also refer to
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371912/how-to-make-an-html-css-js-color-changing-background-like-kahoot-it-has)

Answer (score 0):

```css
@keyframes bgcolor {
    0% {
        background-color: #45a3e5
    }

    30% {
        background-color: #66bf39
    }

    60% {
        background-color: #eb670f
    }

    90% {
        background-color: #f35
    }

    100% {
        background-color: #864cbf
    }
}

body {
    -webkit-animation: bgcolor 20s infinite;
    animation: bgcolor 10s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```